# Why is $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{\mu (k)}{k\phi (k)} = \prod_p \left( 1- 1/(p(p-1))\right)$?

Tags: number-theory

That's the actual question - why is $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{\mu (k)}{k\phi (k)} = \prod_p \left( 1- \frac{1}{p(p-1)}\right)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

For prime $p,$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{\mu (k)}{k\phi (k)}=\prod_p\left[\sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{\mu (p^r)}{p^r\phi (p^r)}\right]$$

Now,
$$\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{\mu (p^r)}{p^r\phi (p^r)}=1+\frac{(-1)}{p(p-1)}+0$$

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot, but: If I want to calculate $\sum_{r=0}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^r}{p^rp^{r-1}(p-1)}=\frac{1}{p(p-1)}\sum_{r=0}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^r}{p^{2r}}=\frac{1}{p(p-1)}\cdot \frac{p^2}{p^2+1}$, but that is not that what I wanted...

Comment: @sBs, Have you found any mistake here?

Comment: where? In your or my post? I can't find any mistake

Comment: @sBs, No no, my post

Comment: Oh yes I did (in my post), first step - but then I got at the end $\frac{p^3}{(p^2+1)(p-1)}$...is that what I wanted?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee when we decompose it into a euler product $\mu(p^r) = 0$, for $r \ge 2$ .. so $\prod\limits_{p} \left(1+\frac{\mu(p)}{p\phi(p)}\right) = \prod\limits_{p} \left(1-\frac{1}{p(p-1)}\right)$

Comment: @r9m, Sorry for the mistake. Thanks anyway

Comment: @sBs, Please find the edited version and r9m's comment